# Replace buffered value with latest in TPL Dataflow

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I need help with making a TPL Dataflow pipeline **update** an input buffer with the **latest** value.

I am subscribed to a live stream of elements, which are posted one by one onto a dataflow pipeline. Each element is processed, which takes some time - it takes significantly more time to process one element than what it takes to produce it (i.e. fast producer, slow consumer).

However, if there are multiple elements on the input queue with the same identity, only the most recent one needs processing. The intermediate ones can be discarded. This is the part I am having trouble figuring out.

**Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:**

```cs
public record Bid(int Id, int Value);

async Task Main()
{
    // This block is just here to log that an input is received.
    var startBlock = new TransformBlock<Bid, Bid>(d =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input: {0} ({1})", d.Id, d.Value);
            return d;
        });

//TODO: Check for duplicate identity (Bid.Id) and replace the
// current element with the most recent one.
    var updateWithMostRecentBlock = new TransformBlock<Bid, Bid>(d => d);
    
    var processBlock = new TransformBlock<Bid, Bid>(async d =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing: {0} ({1})", d.Id, d.Value);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return d;
        });

    var finishBlock = new ActionBlock<Bid>(d =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done: {0} ({1})", d.Id, d.Value);
        });


    var propagateCompletion = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
    startBlock.LinkTo(updateWithMostRecentBlock, propagateCompletion);
    updateWithMostRecentBlock.LinkTo(processBlock, propagateCompletion);
    processBlock.LinkTo(finishBlock, propagateCompletion);


    var data = new[]
        {
            new Bid(1, 0), // Processed immediately
            new Bid(1, 1), // Replaced with (1,2)
            new Bid(2, 0), // Replaced with (2,1)
            new Bid(1, 2), // Queued
            new Bid(2, 1)  // Queued
        };
    foreach (var d in data)
        startBlock.Post(d);

    startBlock.Complete();
    await finishBlock.Completion;
}
```

When `processBlock` is ready to receive the next element, I want `updateWithMostRecentBlock` to provide only the most relevant element.

**Actual output:**

```
Input: 1 (0)
Input: 1 (1)
Input: 2 (0)
Input: 1 (2)
Input: 2 (1)
Processing: 1 (0)
Processing: 1 (1)
Done: 1 (0)
Processing: 2 (0)
Done: 1 (1)
Processing: 1 (2)
Done: 2 (0)
Processing: 2 (1)
Done: 1 (2)
Done: 2 (1)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Input: 1 (0)       // Immediately processed
Input: 1 (1)       // Replaced by (1,2)
Input: 2 (0)       // Replaced by (2,1)
Input: 1 (2)       // Queued
Input: 2 (1)       // Queued
Processing: 1 (0)
Done: 1 (0)
Processing: 1 (2)
Done: 1 (2)
Processing: 2 (1)
Done: 2 (1)
```

**Hint:**
Stephen Toub has [an elegant solution](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20690#issuecomment-287751004) to the exact opposite of what I'm trying to achieve. His solution rejects all incoming elements and retains the oldest one.

Comment: Its probably easier to just create your own block with the logic you need.

Comment: There are many many ways to achieve this, though For instance, you could have a synchronised dictionary based around a key of your choosing, when item gets buffed just update the item in the dictionary, when its dequeued check for the item, use it, delete the dictionary item. Obviously there is a lot left to the imagination, but very doable

Comment: I tried with a custom block, but can't get it to work because the `processBlock` does not pull the next element when it's ready - `updateWithMostRecentBlock` has to push it. That would require buffering with some trigger that fires when the `processBlock` is ready, which is information not available. I haven't figured out how to gain access to the `processBlock`'s input buffer...

Comment: I would imagine you would need to use a custom block entirely as a buffer, with its target block with a bounded capacity of one to create the appropriate back pressure on your custom block, when the messaged is consumed is when you would do the replacement. Note, its been a while since i have built a custom block, but hopefully someone has time to get these details sorted for you

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for answering my own question, but @TheGeneral brought me on the right track with his hint about **bounded capacity**.

I had to configure the `processBlock` to set bounded capacity to 1:

```cs
    var processBlock = new TransformBlock<Bid, Bid>(
        async d =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processing: {0} ({1})", d.Id, d.Value);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return d;
            },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 1
            });
```

Then I replaced the `updateWithMostRecentBlock` with a custom block that has this implementation:

```cs
public class DiscardAndReplaceDuplicatesBlock<TValue, TKey> : IPropagatorBlock<TValue, TValue>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    private readonly ITargetBlock<TValue> _target;
    private readonly IReceivableSourceBlock<TValue> _source;

    public DiscardAndReplaceDuplicatesBlock(Func<TValue, TKey> keyAccessor)
    {
        var buffer = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, (TValue Value, Task Task, CancellationTokenSource Token)>();
        var outgoing = new BufferBlock<TValue>(new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 1,
                MaxMessagesPerTask = 1
            });
        var incoming = new ActionBlock<TValue>(value =>
            {
                var key = keyAccessor(value);
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                var isQueued = buffer.TryGetValue(key, out var previous);
                if (isQueued)
                {
                    buffer.TryRemove(key, out var current);
                    Console.WriteLine("Remove: {0}", current.Value);

                    if (!previous.Task.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        previous.Token.Cancel();
                        previous.Token.Dispose();
                        Console.WriteLine("Cancel: {0}", current.Value);
                    }
                }

                var task = outgoing.SendAsync(value, cts.Token);
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    cts.Dispose();
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", value);
                    return;
                }

                buffer.AddOrUpdate(key, (value, task, cts), (k, t) => (value, task, cts));
                Console.WriteLine("Buffered: {0}", value);
            });

        incoming.Completion.ContinueWith(
            async t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        ((ITargetBlock<TValue>)outgoing).Fault(t.Exception.InnerException);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await WaitForBufferToCompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                        outgoing.Complete();
                    }
                },
            default,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);

        Task WaitForBufferToCompleteAsync()
        {
            if (!buffer.Any())
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            var buffered = buffer.Where(kvp => !kvp.Value.Task.IsCompleted);
            var tasks = buffered.Select(b => b.Value.Task);
            return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        _target = incoming;
        _source = outgoing;
    }

    public Task Completion =>
        _source.Completion;

    public void Complete() =>
        _target.Complete();

    public void Fault(Exception exception) =>
        _target.Fault(exception);

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<TValue> target, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions) =>
        _source.LinkTo(target, linkOptions);

    public TValue ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<TValue> target, out bool messageConsumed) =>
        _source.ConsumeMessage(messageHeader, target, out messageConsumed);

    public DataflowMessageStatus OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, TValue messageValue, ISourceBlock<TValue>? source, bool consumeToAccept) =>
        _target.OfferMessage(messageHeader, messageValue, source, consumeToAccept);

    public bool ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<TValue> target) =>
        _source.ReserveMessage(messageHeader, target);

    public void ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<TValue> target) =>
        _source.ReleaseReservation(messageHeader, target);
}
```

It is not very pretty, and it is not production tested, but it seems to work. In order to actually replace an already dispatched element, I had to retain the cancellation token used so I could cancel an outdated but unprocessed element. I'm not sure this is the best idea so any critique is welcome!

One note, though: This will also process element `(1,1)` because after `(1,0)` has been dispatched to the `processorBlock`, element `(1,1)` is successfully sent to the custom block's output buffer. I don't think this can be avoided.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Answering our own questions is welcome [and actually encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here! 

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this problem:

```
public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateTransformBlockDropOldestByKey<TInput, TOutput, TKey>(
    Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> transform,
    Func<TInput, TKey> keySelector,
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions = null,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null,
    IProgress<TInput> droppedItems = null)
{
    if (transform == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
    dataflowBlockOptions = dataflowBlockOptions ?? new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
    keyComparer = keyComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TInput>(keyComparer);

    var outputBlock = new TransformManyBlock<TKey, TOutput>(async key =>
    {
        bool removed; TInput removedItem;
        lock (dictionary) removed = dictionary.Remove(key, out removedItem);
        if (!removed) return Enumerable.Empty<TOutput>();
        return new[] { await transform(removedItem).ConfigureAwait(false) };
    }, dataflowBlockOptions);

    var inputBlock = new ActionBlock<TInput>(item =>
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        bool dropped; TInput droppedItem;
        lock (dictionary)
        {
            dropped = dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out droppedItem);
            dictionary[key] = item;
        }
        if (dropped) droppedItems?.Report(droppedItem);
        return outputBlock.SendAsync(key);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 1,
        CancellationToken = dataflowBlockOptions.CancellationToken,
        TaskScheduler = dataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler,
    });

    PropagateCompletion(inputBlock, outputBlock);
    PropagateFailure(outputBlock, inputBlock);

    return DataflowBlock.Encapsulate(inputBlock, outputBlock);

    async void PropagateCompletion(IDataflowBlock source, IDataflowBlock target)
    {
        try { await source.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false); } catch { }
        var ex = source.Completion.IsFaulted ? source.Completion.Exception : null;
        if (ex != null) target.Fault(ex); else target.Complete();
    }

    async void PropagateFailure(IDataflowBlock source, IDataflowBlock target)
    {
        try { await source.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false); } catch { }
        if (source.Completion.IsFaulted) target.Fault(source.Completion.Exception);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var droppedItems = new Progress<Bid>(b =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Dropped: {b.Id} ({b.Value})");
});

var processBlock = CreateTransformBlockDropOldestByKey<Bid, Bid, int>(async b =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Processing: {b.Id} ({b.Value})");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return b;
}, b => b.Id, droppedItems: droppedItems);
```

The reason that the two internal blocks, the `inputBlock` and the `outputBlock` are not linked together directly, is because otherwise a fault in the `outputBlock` could potentially leave the `inputBlock` hanging in a not complete state forever. It is important that if one of the two blocks fail, the other should fail too, so that any pending `SendAsync` operation towards the `inputBlock` to be canceled. The blocks are linked together indirectly, by using the `PropagateCompletion` and `PropagateFailure` methods.

Configuring the `processBlock` with a `BoundedCapacity` should take into account that the block may contain in its input queue keys that may have been dropped, so setting this configuration to a slightly higher value is advised.